# index access by non-clustered index

Tags: sql-server, optimization

If I have two table of data. One has a clustered index CINDEX, the other is a heap HEAP.

Both also have a non-clustered index on the same column - SEARCHCOL

Assume my clustered index columns are the same size as a rowid and therefore the depth of both of the non-clustered index is the same.

Which would take fewer I/O's to fetch a table row...

```
a) SELECT * FROM CINDEX WHERE SEARCHCOL = :1

b) SELECT * FROM HEAP WHERE SEARCHCOL = :1
```

Choose a or b
Explain why
state any assumptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Searchcol` has enough selectivity then the plan should do the expected seek into non-clustered index (identical between the two) and then lookup the clustered index or the heap in order to get all the columns as to satisfy the `*` projection. This later lookup will be faster in a heap (direct search by page:slot) compared to a BTree seek (has to hit 1-2 non leaf pages to land on the leaf page containing the row) *if the heap row was not moved*. If the heap row was moved, then the lookup has to chase the forwarding pointer on a new page, meaning a new logical read IO, and so on until it find the place (if it mover multiple times). So in general a heap would save 1-2 logical read IOs (the non-leaf part of the seek in the lookup).

If the SEARCHCOL is not selective enough and the query hits the [Tipping Point](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx) then all bets are off as one plan would to a clustered index scan in key order, while the other would to a heap scan in allocation order (they would end up roughly the same IO).

But I have to warn that this kind of minutia measurement (1-2 page IOs) are not healthy when making a decision about heap vs. BTree. My take is *always choose BTree unless there are explicit reasons not to*. Explicit reasons would usually be INSERT performance (this is where HEAPs run circles around BTrees) and that implies ETL data load scenarios where the data is loaded into a heap for fast upload performance and then the heap is turned into a clustered index and added with a switch operaiton into the big fact table.

Comment: Maybe that's a minutia in the average SQL Server database... but I make a living tuning one or two IO's out of high performance databases. I think there should be a radiobutton on questions... (x) I need an enterprise big-boy answer or ( ) I have a departmental app with a handful of users and no real SLA. But again I thank you for confirming my suspicion. And the wider the row is, the fewer rows per leaf block, the deeper the b-tree table is vs heap the more "unobtrusive" IO's appear and the more Billions of rows, the deeper again... so Wide or Long tables get worse and worse comparatively.

Comment: Just to be clear it's not the one or two IO's on a single query... it's when that query gets executed 10,000 per minute.

Comment: Fair enough. Comparing Tables Organized with Clustered Indexes versus Heaps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917672.aspx

Comment: Remus, I've read a lot of articles on the net and soooo many are filled with gratuitous assertions. Some articles say, CI's make everything go faster... it's the infamous FASTER = TRUE config setting that is always correct. So I'm trying to tease out fact from myth. I was going to post a long multiple part question but I thought that wouldn't work on SO. So, I'm posting sequential questions, one building on the previous.

Comment: There's a strong community here at SO, I hope you'll get your answers. Sometimes though things are not black or white and more often than not the answer will be 'it depends'...